# Why does a script at the end of the body block the page from loading?

Tags: javascript, alert

If  I add an alert in the page head the alert shows up normally and after clicking on OK the website loads, but when I move the alert into the end of the body element the webpage (according to YT videos) should load immediately but it doesn't. It still waiting on me on clicking "OK".

So where I did mistake?

```html
<body>
  <div id="contact-us">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <p>You can contact Mr Green in various ways ...</p>
    <div class="contact-method">
      <h3>By Phone</h3>
      <p>222-222-FISH</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-method">
      <h3>By Email</h3>
      <p>iammrgreen@green.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-method">
      <h3>By carrier pidgeon</h3>
      <p>To do this, order your podgeon at www.mrgreenspidgeonemporium.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#top">Go to top</a>

  <script>
    alert("Yo Ninja, welcome to my website!");
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Generally better not to use alert, because it can only log strings, and it blocks your thread while it's active (as in the browser will _do nothing_ until it's dismissed). At the very least, use console.log and look at your dev tools console.

Comment: The browser doesn't render the page as it's loading it. It loads the whole thing into memory, executes the JavaScript, then renders it. This allows the JavaScript to modify the DOM before it's displayed.

Comment: JavaScript performs way better than the Dom do. That's why the DOMContentLoaded event listener exists to force yow Js to wait the dom to be mounted

Comment: I actually do not know, I am speculating. But I think that, what happened is that your html is parsed into dom tree and it executed script and before it has it started rendering (because it is inside the body) and `alert` just blocked the main thread so it cannot render unless the alert is canceled. If you want to execute it after body is rendered, you can use `DOMContentLoaded` event or maybe setTimeout since it would put execution of alert at the end of the event loop. For more information and keywords to google you can see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: Ok Thank you guys, it's good to know that there is someone willing to help ..

Apparently Brackets have problem with Live Preview .. because when I open the website normally from the folder everything works as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can do an experiment for example with setTimeout.

In this snippet if the timeout is too small the alert will appear before anything is painted on the screen, slightly bigger and the whole screen gets painted before the alert appears. It doesn't happen in bits.

```
<body>
  <div id="contact-us">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <p>You can contact Mr Green in various ways ...</p>
    <div class="contact-method">
      <h3>By Phone</h3>
      <p>222-222-FISH</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-method">
      <h3>By Email</h3>
      <p>iammrgreen@green.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-method">
      <h3>By carrier pidgeon</h3>
      <p>To do this, order your podgeon at www.mrgreenspidgeonemporium.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#top">Go to top</a>
  <script>


function afterwait() {
  alert("Yo Ninja, welcome to my website!");
}
setTimeout(afterwait, 10);
</script>
</body>
```